# Найти максимальное значение сумм столбцов и строк, а затем все последующие

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Собственно, задание состоит в следующем:

1. сгенерировать прямоугольную матрицу, заданного размера , заполненную целочисленными значениями в заданном диапазоне.
2. составить алгоритм, возвращающий последовательность значений, взятых из матрицы, в соответствии со следующим порядком:

а) сначала находим значение - такое, что выражение: "сумма значений в строке, к которой принадлежит содержащая значение ячейка, и в столбце, к которому она принадлежит - максимальное.

б) находим все последующие значения, для которых результат приведенного выше выражения максимален, при соблюдении условия, что ячейка каждого нового значения не относится к строкам и столбцам, содержащим ячейки ранее найденных значений.

в) значения через ";" вывести в порядке их нахождения алгоритмом.

г) сформировать матрицу размером, совпадающим с исходной матрицы, в ячейках которой, вместо значений, будут находится порядковые номера их выбора алгоритмом, изложенным в пп."а"/"б".
Ячейки, значения которых остались не выбранными по завершении алгоритма, остаются не заполнены.

Пункт 1 организовал вводом значений через пробел и переходом "enter" на следующую строку. При вводе "end", ввод заканчивается. Второй пункт под буквой "а" тоже сделал, дальше завис, хочу после выполнения вернуться назад в цикл, но не знаю как, в голове GoTo, но все это похоже на колхоз, буду рад помощи или намеку с альтернативным решением или продолжением.

```
import numpy as np
b = []
mas =[]
d = ""
while d != "end":
    d = input()
    if d == "end":
        break
    b.append([int(i) for i in d.split()])
c = len(b)# кол-во строк
e = len(b[0])# кол-во столбцов
for i in range (c):
    for j in range (e):
        a=0
arr = np.array(b)
rows, columns = arr.shape
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):  
        if arr[:, j].sum()+arr[i].sum() == max(arr.sum(axis=0))+max(arr.sum(axis=1)):
            print(arr[i, j])
            arr=np.delete(arr,i,axis=0)
            arr=np.delete(arr,j,axis=1)
```

Comment: у вас в первом пункте сказано "сгенерировать". а вы целую простыню с импутами написали зачем-то. то есть, половину приведенного вами кода можно заменить одной строкой.

Comment: я решил сделать ввод, можно, конечно и сгенерировать

Comment: "хочу после выполнения вернуться назад в цикл" - просто оберните это в еще один цикл

Comment: Что-то типа "пока строка или столбец не будет равна нулю?"

Comment: Если честно, я очень плохо понимаю ваше задание, так как оно написано в полустрогой форме и так как вы пишете немного не то, о чем, как мне кажется, в задании говорится. Поэтому я просто говорю, что чтобы вернуться назад в коде нужно использовать цикл. Какой цикл и с каким условием - зависит от трактовки задания. Кажется, что главное условие - пока будет найден хотя бы один элемент, удовлетворяющий условию "сумма значений в строке, к которой принадлежит содержащая значение ячейка, и в столбце, к которому она принадлежит - максимальное"

Comment: Да, до меня дошло, что можно трактовать как через то, что я пишу (удаление использованных строк и столбцов), так и совершенно по-другому с другими результатами (без удаления), и мне кажется, я ушел не в то условие. Спасибо за намёк, уточню и буду думать.

Comment: Не нужно ничего удалять, так вы вообще запутаетесь с нумерацией ячеек. Создавайте список строк и столбцов, которые исключаются из дальнейшей обработки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задание (особенно пункт б)...

```
import numpy as np

MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE = 1, 9
ROWS, COLS = 7, 10

matrix = np.random.randint(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE+1, (ROWS, COLS))
print("Матрица:", matrix, sep="\n")
rows, cols = np.indices(matrix.shape)
matrix = (matrix.sum(axis=0)[cols] + matrix.sum(axis=1)[rows]).astype(np.float128)
print("Суммы:", matrix, sep="\n")

values, indices = [], []
while not np.isnan(matrix).all():
    max_row, max_col = np.unravel_index(np.nanargmax(matrix), matrix.shape)
    values.append(int(matrix[max_row, max_col]))
    indices.append((max_row, max_col))
    matrix[:, max_col] = matrix[max_row, :] = np.nan

print(*values, sep=";")

matrix = np.full(matrix.shape, "")
matrix[tuple(zip(*indices))] = range(len(indices))
print("Нумерация:", matrix, sep="\n")
```

```
Матрица:
[[6 6 9 8 9 4 8 9 4 5]
 [9 2 2 6 7 5 9 5 1 5]
 [8 4 3 1 6 3 2 4 8 8]
 [4 5 3 8 9 2 9 8 2 7]
 [5 5 1 3 1 8 6 3 6 3]
 [5 6 4 4 8 3 1 7 2 6]
 [9 2 9 1 2 9 6 5 4 6]]
Суммы:
[[114.  98.  99.  99. 110. 102. 109. 109.  95. 108.]
 [ 97.  81.  82.  82.  93.  85.  92.  92.  78.  91.]
 [ 93.  77.  78.  78.  89.  81.  88.  88.  74.  87.]
 [103.  87.  88.  88.  99.  91.  98.  98.  84.  97.]
 [ 87.  71.  72.  72.  83.  75.  82.  82.  68.  81.]
 [ 92.  76.  77.  77.  88.  80.  87.  87.  73.  86.]
 [ 99.  83.  84.  84.  95.  87.  94.  94.  80.  93.]]
114;99;94;92;87;80;72
Нумерация:
[['0' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
 ['' '' '' '' '' '' '' '3' '' '']
 ['' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '4']
 ['' '' '' '' '1' '' '' '' '' '']
 ['' '' '6' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
 ['' '' '' '' '' '5' '' '' '' '']
 ['' '' '' '' '' '' '2' '' '' '']]
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float128' Что у меня не так?

Comment: @АндрейКовров Ну, поставьте другой float. Например, float64. Видимо наличие float128 от платформы зависит.

Comment: С матрицами размерностью больше 10 уже работать не будет?

Comment: @АндрейКовров Будет. Почему нет? Только если нужна будет печать матриц, надо будет её реализовать. numpy большие матрицы обрезает при печати.

Comment: работает, если сделать 2 пробела в этой строке matrix = np.full(matrix.shape, "  "), но до "99"